# Change text color of a Ext.ComponentQuery.query

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I'm working with Sencha Architect.

I'm passing values ​​from a localStorage to a displayfield.

```
get_name: function(component, eOpts) {
        let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loginData"));
        name = data["name"];
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('displayfield[name="show_name"]')[0].setValue(name);

    }
```

The value appears normally, but I can't change the font color.

Any idea how I can do this?

I've tried a few things like:

html, style, css.

But the text color remains default

Comment: add cls config to show_name and give the color property to that cls..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text color of your displayfield's value by using the *config* [fieldStyle](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Display.html#cfg-fieldStyle) or setting it programmatically with the *method* [setFieldStyle](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Display.html#method-setFieldStyle) .

So here are your alternatives:

```
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    fieldLabel: 'My Display Field',
    name: 'myField',
    value: '10',
    fieldStyle: { color: "red" }
}
```

OR

```
<displayfield>.setFieldStyle({ color: "red" });
```

Comment: I changed the background color with: Ext.get('show_name').setStyle('background-color','white');.  But for the text it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `background-color`, it has to be `backgroundColor`.

```
    get_name: function(component, eOpts) {
        const field = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('displayfield[name="show_name"]')[0];
        let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loginData")),
            name = data["name"];

        field.setValue(name);
        field.setStyle('backgroundColor','white');
    }
```

And I would not go with Ext.ComponentQuery. Instead you might go with

```
    const form = getFormPanel, // typically this.getView()
         field = form.lookupName('show_name');
```